# Why the app crashes when I set the ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to run an example I found it on a book about the `ListView`. As the book stated, I created the `string-array` in `string.xml` file and the layout of the `ListView` is in `list_item.xml` inside `res->layout` folder.

The problem is that, the app crashes when I run the activity. Can any one tell me where the mistake is?

**Code1**:

```
public class ListViewTestActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] c = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, c));
    }}
```

**string.xml**

```
<resources>

<string name="hello">Hello World, ListViewTestActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">ListViewTest</string>

<string-array
        name="cities">
    <item>Bath</item>
    <item>Birmingham</item>
    <item>Bradford</item>
    <item>Brighton</item>
    <item>Bristol</item>
    <item>Cambridge</item>
    <item>Canterbury</item>
</string-array>
```

**list_item.xml**:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="28dip">
    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**:

```
    05-05 22:45:16.018: E/ArrayAdapter(648): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:347)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
05-05 22:45:16.048: E/AndroidRuntime(648):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:340)
```

Comment: Can you also post the log?
After posting the log we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use that particular layout for the row item then assign an `id` to the `TextView` and pass that in the constructor of the adapter to let the adapter know where to place the data:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="28dip">
</TextView>
```

and in your activity:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.text, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file must be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/monid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="28dip" />
```

Comment: Did you really wrote this line: `android:id="@+id/idyouwant"`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably closing your linear layout in `list_item.xml`.
If that does not work, post log

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a call to setContentView(...) somewhere in onCreate.